# Unity lagging after update?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, game-engine, lag

I've been working on a lightweight game with some friends. Today I updated Unity to 2018.1.0f2, and after about 30 minutes of loading time, I was able to edit my project again.

But all of a sudden, Unity is being very slow. I try playing the game, and it is running at about 2-3 FPS. The current editor mode is DX11, but I tried forcing it to OpenGL and that only made it much worse. My computer should be able to handle it; I have a GTX 1080, 32 GB of RAM, and an i7-8700K.

Can someone please explain what is causing this, and how to fix it?

Also, there is a known bug involving Unity collab being slow. I am not using that.

Comment: Yikes! I'm running latest Unity on an ancient Dell Laptop with Core 2 Duo, a literal Windows Vista sticker w/ Windows 7 upgrade attached to the 13-pound chassis by a process of irreversible molecular annealing, and 4GB of RAM up under the hood, with much less slowdown than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two things:

1) Uninstall all Unity installs you have (2018 and earlier, if you still have them), then re-install 2018.1.0f2 from scratch.

2) Go to your project folder, and delete everything except the dirs `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` (you may delete even this one, but then you need to re-set all project settings from scratch) - remember that if you imported packages via NuGet, you should leave the `Packages` directory too.

Then try to relaunch Unity and load the project by opening it from the Unity launch window and see if it lags again or not.

Let me know how this goes.